# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I am doing SqlServer2008 r2 connectivity with android.

My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=14GRAFICALI\\MSSQLSERVER2008;databaseName=AndroidDB;integrated security=true";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tvData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedData);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);                   

            System.out.println("connected");
            Statement statement=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from AndroidDB");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                tvData.setText(" Data1 : "+resultSet.getString(1)+"  Data 2 : "+resultSet.getNString(2));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code is not working and giving me error on line:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

But when i checked this path, file was there with above path.

Have a look at it:

[image]

What can be the problem?

Please help me.

**EDIT**

Javabuildpath:[image]

Libs:

[image]

Comment: can you post a screen of java build path at your project properties?

Comment: @OnurA. sir plz have a look at it

Comment: localhost should be `10.0.2.2`

Comment: @SunilMishra sir but there is no webservice involved in it? still its ok?

Comment: Have you also add jar file in libs folder??

Comment: add your all the libraries in libs folder and then import them in your project.

Comment: @PiyushGupta drag and drop

Comment: @MahaveerMuttha plz see my libs folder, how can i import it now?

Comment: but your `SQL server` is running on PC right?

Comment: possibly your jar doesn't contain that class, double check it, and btw localhost should be 10.0.2.2

Comment: Android != Java, a Java driver won't work unless recompiled specifically for Android.

Comment: @SunilMishra yes, its on my PC

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672012/class-not-found-although-particular-jar-is-added-in-project?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Few Steps That need to be foolwed in case when we are connecting Android to directly a SQLServer.

I have mentioned each and every detailed steps in my answer over here:

[Class not found although particular jar is added in project (android to sqlserver without webservice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672012/class-not-found-although-particular-jar-is-added-in-project-android-to-sqlserve?answertab=active#tab-top)

Please follow the stages and i am sure you will overcome all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the jar which contains SQLServerDriver class in your classpath as explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100).

If you are using Eclipse, right click on your project, then Java Build Path, under Libraries tab, check if the jar is there and no other version of the same jar exists.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread on the microsoft msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4799819a-27fd-4292-a3d8-f114207c20b2/using-the-jdbc-driver-with-android) using a different JDBC driver should work. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

The CLASSPATH variable is the search string that Java Virtual Machine (JVM) uses to locate the JDBC drivers on your computer. If the drivers are not listed in your CLASSPATH variable, you receive the following error message when you try to load the driver:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/microsoft/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerDriver

The JDBC driver is not part of the Java SDK. If you want to use it, you must set the classpath to include the sqljdbc.jar file or the sqljdbc4.jar file. If the classpath is missing an entry for sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar, your application will throw the common "Class not found" exception.

The sqljdbc.jar file and sqljdbc4.jar file are installed in the following location:

```
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc.jar
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc4.jar
```

The following is an example of the CLASSPATH statement that is used for a Windows application:

```
CLASSPATH =.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc.jar
```

The following is an example of the CLASSPATH statement that is used for a Unix/Linux application:

```
CLASSPATH =.:/home/usr1/mssqlserverjdbc/Driver/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc.jar
```

You must make sure that the CLASSPATH statement contains only one Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server, such as either sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar.